# DSUM - Complex Criteria

Tags: excel

I have the following table:

[image]

I need to sum the values of the rows which satisfy the following criteria:

COUNTRY = USA  AND  Date IS in First Semester  AND    Names Contains Andrew.

I am trying to use the function DSUM: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/dsum-HP005209069.aspx

But I am having problems with the Date criteria and the Names criteria.

Does any one knows how to define those criteria to be used with DSUM?

Comment: your date column seems to contain text strings instead of date values. In my opinion date should be written as `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the dates are correctly formatted as dates (and the values as numbers) then, with the following sample data:

[image: Sample data]

then the following seems to work for both SUMIFS and DSUM, giving totals of 340:

[image: Formulas]

I haven't tested extensively though, and I don't know what a semester is ;)

Answer (score 0):

if your data is in A1:D6, in a blank cell (say G2) enter:

```
=AND(A2="USA",MONTH(B2)<7,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Andrew",D2)))
```

and ensure G1 is blank. now you can use

```
=DSUM(A1:D6,"Value",G1:G2)
```